# How to set a active link as default when page first time load using angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, AfterContentInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {MenuService} from './menu.service';
import {OrderByPipe} from '../shared/pipes/OrderBy';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
 selector: 'category',
 directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgFor],
 providers: [
    MenuService
 ],
 pipes: [OrderByPipe],
 template: `
    <div class="category-list" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="20" id="nav2"> 
     <span class="category-list-item" *ngFor="#item of items | orderBy :['sort_order']"
        (click)="change(item)"
        [ngClass]="{'active':item.active}">
        <a id="elementID">{{item.name}}</a>
     </span>
 </div>

`
})

export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
@Input() items:any;
@Output('change') changeEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

change(item:any): void {
    this.items.map((o:any)=> { o.active=false;});
    item.active = true;
    this.changeEmitter.emit(item);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0// $('#elementID').offset().top + 200
    }, 300);
}
ngOnInit() {
    // this.items.map((o:Object)=> { o.active=false;});
    // this.items[0].active=true;
        $('#nav2').affix({
            offset: { top: 100 }
        });
}
ngAfterContentInit() {
            // Component content has been initialized
    // console.log(this.items);
  }
}


[![current behavior of nav link][1]][1]
```

[image: Expected behavior of nav link, it is getting background color but only after clicking on any of the link]

I am using angular 2 for product listing page. I am trying to give background color to the link after clicking and it is working fine but the problem is when first time page is loaded, the first link should be default active with bg color.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this in the `ngOnInit` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.items.map((o:any)=> { o.active=false;});
  this.items[0].active = true;
}
```

Don't forget to check that `this.items` isn't undefined and corresponds to an array...